# Swift Perfect Heroku Failed to detect set buildpack

Tags: swift, heroku, perfect

I'm trying to deploy a [Perfect](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect) app to Heroku, but I have only succeeded in getting the Swift compiler to run on Herolu with Perfect's own [build pack](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Heroku-Buildpack). However, this build pack uses Swift 2.2 and my app runs on Swift 3.

I have then tried a variety of other build packs, including [vapor](https://github.com/vapor/heroku-buildpack), [neonichu](https://github.com/neonichu/swift-buildpack), and the seemingly most popular one: [kylef](https://github.com/kylef/heroku-buildpack-swift).

But for everyone of them I get the same error message when pushing to Heroku:

```
Failed to detect set buildpack <url>.git
```

I feel I have exhausted my options, so this is my final try.

Answer (score 1):

The makefile in your Heroku example project is referencing Ubuntu 14.0.4, the default Heroku app now is 16.0.4 as of May 2017. You need to set the ubuntu stack to cedar-14, and the swift app will deploy fine:

$ heroku stack:set cedar-14 -a example-app

$ git commit -m "update to cedar-14" --allow-empty

$ git push heroku master

Answer (score 0):

I succeed with the error. The project structure didn't work.

Please use this project structure: 
https://github.com/taplin/Perfect-Heroku-Buildpack-Example

I was linking this Buildpack at heroku:
https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Heroku-Buildpack

It worked fine for me. All other instructions you can take out of the video:
http://perfect.org/heroku-buildpack-for-perfect-and-swift.html

[image: The project structure]